# Arcgis for javascript—how to decide what layer to use

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

Here’s the description of the feature: I got multi-mapserver from the Arcgis Serve,and I want to create a map to display on webbrower,but I don’t know what type is the server is,how can I decide what layer to use when I new a map instance,and add the layer to the map.
If u have any idea please help me!!this has drive me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST metadata for a service will tell you whether the service is cached or not. Look for the "Single Fused Map Cache" property.

If the service is cached (i.e. already has tiles), use the 
[TileLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-TileLayer.html).  If it's not cached use [MapImageLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-MapImageLayer.html).

Example 1: https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/MtBaldy_BaseMap/MapServer has "Single Fused Map Cache: true" -> so use [TileLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-TileLayer.html).

Example 2: https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/911CallsHotspot/MapServer has "Single Fused Map Cache: false" -> so use [MapImageLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-MapImageLayer.html).